# Matrix derivative for log-likelihood of multivariate gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am having some problems with regards to derivatives of the parameters for factor analysis. I am pretty certain I constructed the negative log likelihood (for a multivariate gaussian where $\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi}$ can be thought of as the covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$) correctly. ($\ell(\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{\Psi})$ is the negative log-likelihood)

In particular I am struggling with the derivatives w.r.t. to the parameters U and Psi (Psi is a diagonal matrix).

You can see my solution below but especially for the d/dU I am unsure since I cannot wrap my head around $\nabla_{\mathbf{U}} \log |\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi}|$ where $|.|$ is the absolute value of the determinant

Any hints to if my calculations are correct would be appreciated!

\begin{align}
\log\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{X}; \mathbf{U}, \mathbf{\Psi}) &= \log \prod_{i=1}^n \big( (2\pi)^{-m/2} |\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi}|^{-1/2} \exp \big(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}_i^T(\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1}\mathbf{x}_i)\big) \big)\\
&= - \frac{nm}{2} \log 2\pi - \frac{n}{2} \log |\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi}| - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i^T(\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1}\mathbf{x}_i \\
&= C - \frac{n}{2} \log |\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi}| - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i^T(\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1}\mathbf{x}_i \qquad \text{C can be dropped}\\
\ell(\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{\Psi}) &= \frac{n}{2} \log |\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi}| + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i^T(\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1}\mathbf{x}_i 
\end{align}

I constructed the derivatives w.r.t. $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{\Psi}$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\mathbf{U}} \ell(\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{\Psi}) &= n (\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1} \mathbf{U} - (\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} (\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1} \mathbf{U} \\
\nabla_{\mathbf{\Psi}} \ell(\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{\Psi}) &= \frac{n}{2} (\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1} - \frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} (\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^T + \mathbf{\Psi})^{-1}
\end{align}

Comment: Psi should be constrained, shouldn't it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that Psi is a diagonal matrix, i updated my post